# Using pivot in SQL Server not returning desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have two tables like this:

```
**tblTagDescription**
```

[image]

```
and  **tblDataLog**
```

[image]

Now I want to show record of any specific group and in one there might be same group for multiple id in `tbltagdescription`. And id of `tbltagdescription` is foreign key for `tblDataLog` as `TagDescID`.

Here 'Group1' has 10 ID as from 1 to 10. and there might be multiple record for these ID (from 1 to 10) in tbldatalog. I want these ID from 1 to as columns. For this I used pivot:

```
DECLARE @COlsID NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Group NVARCHAR(50) = 'Group1'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MYTABLE') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ##MYTABLE

SELECT 
    @COlsID = COALESCE(@ColsID + '],[','') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), z.TagDescID)  
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50 tblDataLog.TagDescID 
     FROM tblDataLog 
     INNER JOIN tblTagDescription ON tblDataLog.TagDescID = tblTagDescription.ID 
     ORDER BY tblDataLog.TagDescID) z  

SET @COlsID='[' + @COlsID + ']'

SET @SQL='select [DATE],SHIFT, ' + @COlsID + ' into ##MYTABLE from ( select [Date], Value, 
                     (CASE  
                                WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>6 and (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<14) THEN ''A'' 
                                WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>=14 and (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<22) THEN ''B'' 
                                WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>=22 or (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<6) THEN ''C'' 
                            END )AS SHIFT 

                     from tblDataLog )d pivot(max(Value) for TagDescID in (' + @COlsID + ')) piv;'

        EXEC (@SQL)
```

Now when I execute this statement, I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'TagDescID'

but there is this column in `tbldatalog`. How to solve this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need TagDescID column in subquery.

```
DECLARE @COlsID NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @COlsAlias NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Group NVARCHAR(50) = 'Group1'

SELECT 
   @COlsID = @ColsID + ',' + z.TagDescID, 
   @COlsAlias = @COlsAlias + ',' + z.TagDescID + ' AS ' + z.ReportTag   
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50 tblDataLog.TagDescID ID,  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), tblDataLog.TagDescID )) TagDescID, QUOTENAME(tblTagDescription.ReportTag) ReportTag 
     FROM tblDataLog 
        INNER JOIN tblTagDescription ON tblDataLog.TagDescID = tblTagDescription.ID 
     ORDER BY tblDataLog.TagDescID 
     ) z

SET @COlsID= STUFF(@COlsID,1,1,'')
SET @COlsAlias= STUFF(@COlsAlias,1,1,'')

SET @SQL='select [DATE],SHIFT, ' + @COlsAlias + ' into ##MYTABLE from ( select [Date], Value, TagDescID,
                     (CASE  
                                WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>6 and (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<14) THEN ''A'' 
                                WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>=14 and (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<22) THEN ''B'' 
                                WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>=22 or (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<6) THEN ''C'' 
                            END )AS SHIFT 

                     from tblDataLog )d pivot(max(Value) for TagDescID in (' + @COlsID + ')) piv;'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: if possibel how to rename each value in @COlsID to tblTagDescription.ReportTag. Kindly do if possible.

Comment: You can use ReportTag column instead of TagDescID while getting column names and in dynamic subquery SQL

Comment: But ReportTag is not available in both column only Id of tblTagDescription is foreign key as TgDescID in tblDataLog

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 and 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: I changed concat part.

Comment: It is fine almost but ordering is not so right. The order showing is 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 which should be 1 to 10

Comment: It Works perfect now for me. Thanks a lot